# Determine all norm-preserving linear extensions for a functional from the subspace $\{(x,y,z): z=0 \}$ of $\mathbb R^3$.

Tags: functional-analysis, hahn-banach-theorem

> Given the subspace $Y=\{(x,y,z): z=0 \}$ of $\mathbb R^3$, I would like to determine all norm-preserving linear extensions for the functional
>
> $$f(x):= a \cdot x$$
>
> where $a $ is some fixed vector of the form $(a_1,a_2,0)$

---

Here norm-preserving linear extension $g $ is any functional defined on all of $\mathbb R^3 $, such that $g(x)=f(x)$ for $x \in Y$, and such that $\|g \| = \|f \| $. And such an extension is possible by the Hahn-Banch Theorem.

---

I'm not sure how to approach the problem but I believe I can see the following:

The function $f $ would in fact be defined also as a function from $\mathbb R^3 $ and would still be linear as such. Thus this is one possible extension?

> Is it possible to extend $f $ so that it is "an other function on $\mathbb R^3 \setminus Y $"? Or will this break down the linearity?

Much grateful for any help provided!

Comment: Using the Euclidean norm?

Comment: Yes I'm using the Euclidean norm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The norm of the functional $f(x) = a^T x$ is $\|a\|$. On $Y$, $f$ has norm $\sqrt{a_1^2 + a_2^2}$, hence if extended to the entire space, we must have $\bar{a} = (a_1,a_2,a_3)^T$
for some $a_3$. Hence the only way the norm can be preserved is if $a_3=0$.

Comment: Thank you! But how do we make sure that only extensions of the form $g(x) = \bar{a} x $ are possible?

Comment: All linear functionals on $\mathbb{R}^3$ are of the form $b^Tx$ for some $b$. It is immediate that $b_1=a_1$, $b_2=a_2$ by taking $x=(1,0,0)^T $ and $x=(0,1,0)^T$.

Comment: Ah that fact is due to Riesz theorem, isn't it so?

Comment: Or the fact that $e_1,e_2,e_3$ form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.